# MySQL: версионирование операций вставки, обновления и удаления данных

Tags: c#, mysql

Имеется код он полностью выполняет свои требование, но возникла проблема появилась необходимость вести историю изменений в базе.

```
Class1.Adapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dist ORDER BY `Номер`",
                new MySqlConnection(Class1.ConString.ToString()));
            var builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(Class1.Adapter1);
            Class1.Adapter1.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            Class1.Adapter1.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
            Class1.Adapter1.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
            Class1.Adapter1.Fill(Class1.Dt1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Class1.Dt1;
            dataGridView1.DoubleBuffered(true);
```

**UPD**
Структура базы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желательно полностью все данные до и после редактирования той или оной строки в датагриде.

прошу помочь с реализацией данной задумки

Comment: Если не сложно опишите подробнее историю каких изменений вы хотите вести? Схемы базы данных или данных в самой базе?

Comment: @cheops Добавил

Comment: @cheops данных в самой в базе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я взял на себя смелость воспроизвести вашу таблицу, если названия полей не совпадут, вам следует поправить их на свои. Пусть имеется исходная таблица `dist` со следующей структурой.

```
CREATE TABLE dist (
  number varchar(380) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  department text NOT NULL,
  account text NOT NULL,
  query text NOT NULL,
  until_at datetime NOT NULL,
  fio text NOT NULL,
  comment text NOT NULL,
  state text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (number)
);
```

Для того, чтобы хранить историю нам потребуется таблица `dist_history` в которой будут поля для новых и старых значений (префиксы `new_` и `old_`), первичный ключ `id` (так как мы не можем тут выбрать в качестве такого поле `number` - оно будет многократно повторяться), время операции `create_at` и название операции `operation`

```
CREATE TABLE dist_history (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  new_number varchar(380) DEFAULT NULL,
  new_department text,
  new_account text,
  new_query text,
  new_until_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  new_fio text,
  new_comment text,
  new_state text,

  old_number varchar(380) DEFAULT NULL,
  old_department text,
  old_account text,
  old_query text,
  old_until_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  old_fio text,
  old_comment text,
  old_state text,

  create_at datetime NOT NULL,
  operation varchar(20) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Будем логгировать три операции: создание (`INSERT`), обновление (`UPDATE`) и удаление (`DELETE`). Название операции будем помещать в поле `dist_history.operation` (в конечной базе данных это поле можно нормализовать и хранить в таблице `dist_history` только внешний ключ операции, сами названия можно вынести в отдельную таблицу).

Заполнять лог-таблицу, как правильно указал Marat Batalandabad, лучше всего триггерами. Нам потребуется три триггера под каждый из типов запросов.

Для операции вставки `INSERT`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_dist AFTER INSERT ON dist
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    dist_history
  VALUES (
    NULL,
    NEW.number,
    NEW.department,
    NEW.account,
    NEW.query,
    NEW.until_at,
    NEW.fio,
    NEW.comment,
    NEW.state,

    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,

    NOW(),
    'insert');
END//
```

Для операции обновления `UPDATE`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_dist AFTER UPDATE ON dist
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    dist_history
  VALUES (
    NULL,

    NEW.number,
    NEW.department,
    NEW.account,
    NEW.query,
    NEW.until_at,
    NEW.fio,
    NEW.comment,
    NEW.state,

    OLD.number,
    OLD.department,
    OLD.account,
    OLD.query,
    OLD.until_at,
    OLD.fio,
    OLD.comment,
    OLD.state,

    NOW(),
    'update');
END//
```

Для операции удаления `DELETE`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER delete_dist AFTER DELETE ON dist
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    dist_history
  VALUES (
    NULL,

    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,

    OLD.number,
    OLD.department,
    OLD.account,
    OLD.query,
    OLD.until_at,
    OLD.fio,
    OLD.comment,
    OLD.state,

    NOW(),
    'update');
END//
```

Обратите внимание на команду `DELIMITER //`. Триггеры в своем теле содержат точку с запятой, поэтому чтобы интерпретатор запросов mysql не запутался, мы меняем признак окончания запроса при помощи команды `DELIMITER` на `//`. Данный способ работает только в командной строке `mysql`, для других клиентов могут быть другие способы указания признака конца запроса.

Теперь при любая попытка вставить запись в таблицу `dist`, обновить ее или удалить, будет приводить к созданию в таблице `dist_history` записи об этом событии.

Comment: А зачем в таблице "_history" нужны старые значения? Разве не так, что старое значение для записи - это предыдущий ряд из таблицы "_history" ?

Comment: @cache В принципе, да, можно хранить только новые значения, ориентируясь на предыдущие записи. Это позволит сделать таблицу _history более компактной, однако, потребует дополнительные вычисления при необходимости сформировать diff изменений.

Comment: @cheops Возикла проблема ругается на id говорит ячейка не может быть пустой при коррекции

Comment: @cheops т.е он сам не заполняет id

Comment: @cheops всё разобрался, большое спасибо, дай бог тебе здоровья.

Comment: @Павел, большое спасибо за замечание, поправил атрибуты id, чтобы у тех кто будет читать позже все работало.

Answer (score 3):

Повесить триггеры на таблицы и события таблиц которые нужно отслеживать, написать хранимую процедуру, которая будет сохранять данные об изменениях, в таблицу со следующими полями

TableName,
FieldName,
OldValue,
NewValue,
EventDateTime,
EventType,
DbUser,

etc...

Comment: А можно поподробней? Так как с триггерами ещё не сталкивался

Comment: Долго расписывать. Триггеры и хранимые процедуры это сущности СУБД. Вот хороший пример в тему https://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/